# How to set Dropdownlist DataValueField value from Datasource class has inner class field

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a class(called A) that has another class as a field (called B) Class B has attribute attr in it.

How can we set dropdownlist datavaluefield as B.attr if we set Datasource of dropwdownList to class A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose a property on A to get the value of property in B. As far as I know, this is not directly possible (using instance as property)

```
public class A
{
   public string BAttrValue
   {
      get {

         return this.B.Atrr;
      }
   }
}
```

You can bind the `BAttrValue` to your dropdown list